# How to plot the convolution of dirac delta series with a sine function

Tags: plotting, convolution, periodic-function

I am new to mathematica.
I do the convolution of dirac delta :(DiracDelta(x-10)" with "sine(t),t=0-pi". How to plot the output ? Theoretically, the full wave should appear at the location of the singularity.

Comment: Please include the code that you used (and didn't work). Look up the docs for `Convolve`. The very first example should lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using convolution theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem that Fourier of the convolution of two functions is the same as multiplications of their Fourier transforms then

Use `UnitStep` to generate the time limited `sin` function to convolve with, like this

```
Plot[UnitStep[t] UnitStep[Pi - t] Sin[t], {t, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

[image]

and now apply the convolution theorem as above (earlier I forgot to `InverseForurierTranform` at the end, thanks to OleksandrR for noticing)

```
Clear[t, w];
f1 = DiracDelta[t - 10];
f2 = UnitStep[t] UnitStep[Pi - t] Sin[t];
y = FourierTransform[f1, t, w]  FourierTransform[f2 , t, w] ;
conv = InverseFourierTransform[y, w, t]
```

which gives

```
((1/Sign[10 - t] - 1/Sign[10 + Pi - t])*Sin[10 - t])/(2*Sqrt[2*Pi])
```

Plotting it

```
Plot[conv, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Using `Convolve[]` directly as suggested by OleksandrR below seems to be faster on V8.04.

Here is using `Convolve[]` directly. Much faster also. (I do not know why I did not try this first).

```
Clear[t, z];
f1 = DiracDelta[t - 10];
f2 = UnitStep[t] UnitStep[Pi - t] Sin[t];
conv2 = Convolve[f1, f2, t, z]
Plot[conv2, {z, 0, 50}, Exclusions -> None]
```

where conv2 above is

```
Piecewise[{{-Sin[10 - z], 10 <= z <= 10 + Pi}}, 0]
```

[image]

Hopefully not more errors in this now. It is nice that Mathematica offers many ways and functions to analyze a problem.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `InverseFourierTransform` step! (It takes quite a while to find the answer, though. `Convolve` seems to be better than using the convolution theorem in this case.)

Comment: This time the `FourierParameters` were incorrect (have to be consistent between the forward and reverse transforms). I edited your post to correct it, but looks like you just overrode my edits, so if you're actively editing I'll leave it alone...

Comment: Okay! +1 it is, then!